# Flutter Image Picker - Images greyed out / can't select (android)

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using the file picker to select an image on android however when the pop up comes up the images show but I can't select them because they are greyed out (see photo below)

Here's what I'm using to bring up the image picker

```
FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
   allowMultiple: false,
   type: FileType.custom,
   allowedExtensions: ['png', 'jpg'],
);
```

[image]

Comment: Are you testing it on emulator or the physical Device?

Comment: It's on an emulator.

Comment: Can you try on a physical device?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your image extensions are not one of the allowed type of extensions like png or jpg

Comment: Yes i thought too . please check images having jpeg type or what?